# How to check if the mouse is in a text box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent

The user clicks on a text box. After this he selected an item from a list box and the program put the item name in the text box.

The program must uptate the text of the text box only if the user do this path: ***Cliks on Text Box -> Selected Item from ListBox***

If the user does this: ***Clicks on Text Box -> Does Something Else -> Selected Item from ListBox*** the program must not uptade the text of the text box.

How can I do it?

```
private void TextBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      mouse_leave = false;
}

private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(mouse_leave)
     {
           //Do something..
     }         
}
```

Comment: This is WinForms, right?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Sweeper yes this is WinForms.

Comment: " After this he selected an item from a list box and the program put the item name in the text box"...if you want to do that, this doesn't require you do know anything about the mouse, as far as I can see. A user could easily carry out this action entirely using keyboard shortcuts anyway.

Comment: @ADyson check my question now.

Comment: "f the user does this: Clicks on Text Box -> Does Something Else -> Selected Item from ListBox the program must not uptade the text of the text box."...why does it matter if they do something else in between, out of interest? And like I said before, why are you only interested in mouse clicks? Some users do not use the mouse. Some actually _cannot_ use it (e.g. if they are disabled). Your requirement is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the selected item value as shown in the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool isUpdated = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object  sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.isUpdated)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
            this.isUpdated = false;
        }

    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.isUpdated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this works but change the text of textboxt everytime. I want to change the text only when the user clicks on the textbox and after clicks on a item in the texbox.

Comment: Unable to understand your exact scenario. Do you mean the following scenario:-
1. Go to textbox
2. Select the item from the list box.
3. The selected value should be visible in the textbox.
If the user selects again from the list box without moving the cursor first to textbox then the text will not be changed as he doesn't follow the path of textbox->listbox selection.

Comment: @Giovanni kindly check now.

Comment: Thanks you, but if the User does this steps in the following order the program update the text box anyway: 1. Clicks on text box 2. Does something else 3. Selected a item from list box. If the user does the previous steps the program must not uptade the text box.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly , you should do this .

1. define Public variable .

   var selectedTextBox;
2. when user click on TextBox ,you should save this TextBox name into variable in Step 1.

   ```
      private void TextBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         selectedTextBox=TextBox.Name ; // Or This.Name;
   }
   ```
3. then, when user click on item in listBox, you should take selected value and show in Selected TextBox in Step 2 .

   private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       selectedTextBox.Text = ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
       }

Comment: This is nice, but if the user does this sequence the program add however the text to  the text box: _clicks on textbox - does something esle - clicks on item in listbox_